# SUM result is double what it should be

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, duplicates

I am having an issue where the result of my query is double what it should be. My immediate assumption is that this is being summed twice to produce this result. I am dealing with a view which selects from standard tables and i have been unable to find it being summed again anywhere else. My next thought is that a join somewhere must be creating duplicates which is allowing the same value to be summed twice and creating the error.

Its a large view but i have narrowed it down to one area

```
SELECT

F.[Person],
PP.[Team],
SUM(F.[Figure])

from (                   
SELECT Distinct  Year([Date]) 'Year' 
,Month([Date]) 'Month'
,convert(varchar(3),Datename(Month,[Date])) 'Mth' 
,[Person]
from Figure F

Union all

Select Distinct
[Year]
,[Month]
,[Mth]
,[Person]

FROM Person P

)g

Left join [Person2] PP
on PP.Code = g.[Person] 

  GROUP BY 
  P.[Person],
  PP.[Team]
```

I feel as though maybe its something to do with the union but ive never really seen anything like this before. Can anyone help on why this might be creating the double sum or how i can remove this error?

Thanks

Comment: try union instead union all? just to avoid dups?

Comment: add sample data with expected output

Comment: may be because of the table persons2, if any duplicate on PP.Code then it will result in wrong sum

Comment: I will try and get some data together but its difficult because its large. Is there any reason why a join would create duplicates? I have never experienced this before. Could this be the case because of non-uniqueness in tables?

Comment: first verify that your query is returning the correct result before you try to SUM() it. Remove the `GROUP BY` and verify the result first

Comment: How  is your inner query data looks like .can you show some sample data ..??

Comment: thanks @MiloBellano, turns out it was the union all

Comment: I have posted the answer if you are happy with it you can approve and close the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in comment you said UNION works, I post here answer so if you want you can approve it :)

```
from (                   
Distinct  Year([Date]) 'Year' 
,Month([Date]) 'Month'
convert(varchar(3),Datename(Month,[Date])) 'Mth' 
,[Person]
from Figure F

Union  --all will includes dups, so let's use just union
Select Distinct
[Year]
[Month]
,[Mth]
,[Person]

FROM Person P

)g

Left join [Person2] PP
on PP.Code = g.[Person] 

 GROUP BY 
  P.[Person],
  PP.[Team]
```

happy that I helped!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your table "Person2" has some duplicates on the field "Code".

You'd normally expect Code to be your primary key, which would make it unique, but just in case, you could check this by a simple statement like:

```
select
    Code,
    COUNT(Code)
from
    Person2
group by
    Code
having
    COUNT(Code) >= 2
order by 
    Code
```

If there are indeed duplicates, then you would need to either ensure that the duplicates are removed, or have a secondary field to join onto (if there is some element of difference between them).